# Handling cookies in iPhone apps

Tags: php, iphone, cookies, ios4

I have PHP application for offers. In this application when user log in I start new session and save him id in that way `$_SESSION['id'] = $id`. How can I use this variable in my iphone application. I think I can use cookies. But when I create cookie in the start of application how can I use value of this cookie in next screen. If you can give some start point, I'd be glad. I'm developing native application.

Comment: What app you are developing, web application or native?

Comment: Forget about cookie here you have ojects. What you rely want to do?

Comment: But how can I get customer id?

Comment: You can read the last one from your database and increment it

Comment: My user have id that is stored in DB. I want get this id.

Comment: So you'll be linking your app to server? Or will it be an offline app with DB in the app itself?

Comment: @Gurpartap Singh Yes. Can I store id in my local db and when I need it to get from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Apple's [URL Loading System](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html) to access your web site, then you get cookie storage and handling for free with [`NSHTTPCookieStorage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Another good alternative that uses this system is ASIHTTPRequest, which gives you both more control and is easier to use.